# How can I match lines in a file to individual file output locations

Tags: powershell

My input data in a single file

```
location1
location2
location3
```

I have created some empty files in the existing folder e.g 1.txt 2.txt 2.txt

my output should be

- location1 should append to 1.txt
- location2 should append to 2.txt
- location3 should append to 3.txt

---

```
$source=Get-Content -Path "E:\videofiles\filename.txt"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path E:\videofiles\*.avsi 
foreach ($data in  $source)
{

    for ($i=1; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) # enter code here
    {
        $outfile= $files[$i].FullName 
        $outfile
        $data #enter code here
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know location1 goes to 1.txt? They share integers? I do not see any attempt to match your `$data` to its output source

Comment: location 1 goes to 1.txt or 2.txt 0r 3.txt but no problem but i need each file should contain only one location